# What would be the best approach to scrape multiple websites using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping

With Nokogiri, one needs to specify the CSS classes to fetch the data contained using at_css. But how can we approach the same problem when the requirement is to scrape multiple websites, where the design and the CSS classes used would vary?

Comment: Although I have answered, I think this question is quite vague, and you should present your work so far, and what your problems are with it. If that is not code, but perhaps an OO structure/design, then that would still be an improvement to the question.

Comment: you're asking how you can find some data on a webpage and you've told us you don't know the css class, but you didn't tell us what you do know about that data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sites and scraping goals are similar enough, this is done by maintaining some data (either in code or in DB) about each target site, including paths to relevant data.

If the pages are radically different, then you usually have no choice but to write bespoke code for each page.

You can combine the strategies, and have part of your data a designation of which code to use (in Ruby, which scraper `Class` or `Module` to invoke), and the remainder of the data specifying suitable parameters.

Usually the strategies and code evolve over time, it is unlikely you will start with a full understanding of how to scrape all targets. Constant re-factoring is a good development model here, if one goal is to have a maintainable codebase.

Answer (score 1):

There are no magical solutions. You have to investigate the structure of each page and implement scraping solutions.

You should also adhere to website's copyright policy.

```
"The act of screen scraping also presents other legal risks, such as 
infringement of copyright, trade marks, database rights and a breach 
of website terms and conditions"
```

Comment: +1 for referencing copyright policy. If OPs intent is to provide some kind of meta-service, then not adhering to this will expose the meta-service to risk of legal action.

Comment: by all means bear the policies of the websites in mind, but just because something's against T&Cs it doesn't always make it illegal, and more often than not in the case of web scraping it most certainly isn't illegal -- the companies would just rather you believed it was.